# Assigning current date as a defaulte value using Joi validator

Tags: node.js, typescript, joi

I am working with Joi validator and Node js and trying to assign the current date to an attribute using Joi, I have tried these two alternatives but neither one worked for me

```
        createdAt: Joi.date().default(new Date(Date.now()))
```

and

```
    createdAt: Joi.date().default(Joi.date().timestamp())
```

Is this feasible to do with Joi, if yes, would you please help me to figure it out?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Joi.date()` needs a string date format

`Joi.timestamp()` needs a number of milliseconds

Demo

```js
const Joi = require('joi')

const schema = Joi.object({
    createdTimeStamp: Joi.date().timestamp(),
    createdDate: Joi.date()
})

const now = Date.now()
const nowDate = new Date(now)
const result = schema.validate(
    { 
        createdTimeStamp: now,
        createdDate: nowDate
    })

console.log('Joi.date().timestamp(): ' + now)
console.log('Joi.date(): ' + nowDate)
console.log('result: ' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4))
```

Result

```
$ node  test.js
Joi.date().timestamp(): 1676893420897
Joi.date(): Mon Feb 20 2023 06:43:40 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
result: {
    "value": {
        "createdTimeStamp": "2023-02-20T11:43:40.897Z",
        "createdDate": "2023-02-20T11:43:40.897Z"
    }
}
```